# Translating Static Text in Craft3

Tags: localization, craft3

I know that static text translations in still possible but where you put those translations has changed. According to the [documentation](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/changes-in-craft-3.html#static-translation-files) the folder structure should look like this:

```
translations/
  en-US/
    app.php
     site.php
```

but what I can't figure out is where exactly do I put the translations folder. Does it go in the craftcms in vendor?

Answer (score 1):

Just put it on the same level as where the other folders reside, just like:

```
config/...
storage/
templates/
vendor/...
web/...
```

Comment: Awesome thank you!